# How to populate only one column of a table when others can't be null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables : Table A and Table B

Table A and Table B has a common column : `CustomerID`. `Table A` is already populated while `Table B` is empty.

`Table B` has another column `PhoneNo` that can't be null. So, I want to first populate the `CustomerID` column of `Table B` by copying same data from `Table A`, and then add other values to the second column `PhoneNo` (`PhoneNo` CAN'T BE NULL )

The problem is when I do this (inside a stored procedure) :

```
INSERT INTO Table B ( CustomerID, PhoneNo)
      VALUES ( ( SELECT TableA.CustomerID FROM TableA JOIN TableB 
ON TableA.CustomerID = TableB.CustomerID), @PhoneNo)
```

When I try to execute, this gives me an error saying

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression
```

How can I first populate ONLY `CustomerID` column in `TableB` then Add values to the `PhoneNO` column later?

Comment: You can add an empty string `''` (or any value) and update later. See @Patrick's answer.

Comment: And you were lying, the table B was not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your query and changed quite a bit.

The `insert` has two columns, the `select` provides two now. The `join` was removed since it was obsolete. The `values` use was incorrect, using `select` directly now.

```
INSERT
INTO   Table B
( CustomerID
, PhoneNo
)
SELECT CustomerID
,      @PhoneNo
FROM   TableA
```

Comment: When I tried this , if I have 6 entries in CustomerID column , It will add the value I entered for @PhoneNo(let's say 1234567) to ALL 6 records, and I don't want that

Comment: I want to only populate the CustomerID column then ADD new values to the PhoneNo .. I got it .. thanks anyways

Comment: You can't do it like that. It must have a value.

Answer (score 1):

Make the insert without VALUES like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table B ( CustomerID, PhoneNo)
    SELECT TableA.CustomerID, @PhoneNo FROM TableA
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert a record into table B without a phone number. This is exactly what the NOT NULL clause is made for. So it is good you cannot do this. And you should not circumvent this by filling it with ' ' or 'no number' or whatever.

If you want this be made possible then ALTER TABLE b such as to make the phone number nullable.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to do it in following steps. I don't know how do you do that in store procedure but it looks like much more complex to me as you need to pass `@PhoneNo` each time.

1. Since the table `B` is empty (you said it's empty but joining table `B` confused me)

   ```
   INSERT INTO TABLEB(CustomerID)
   SELECT CustomerID
   FROM TABLE A
   ```
2. Now, we could populate `PhoneNo`.

   ```
   UPDATE B
   SET B.PhoneNo = ISNULL(A.PhoneNo, 0)
   FROM TABLEB B
   JOIN TABLEA A ON A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
   ```

You could replace `SET B.PhoneNo = ISNULL(A.PhoneNo, 0)` as `SET B.PhoneNo = @PhoneNo` if you still want to populate them one by one.